# Can't access VPN server through ADSL modem

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, mikrotik

We have `mikrotik` router in our office which takes ethernet WAN(RJ45 plug) as input and connect LAN network. We switched to `ADSL` connection from fibernet connection. Now With `ADSL` connection I can't connect to `mikrotik` router since there is no `ADSL` placeholder in mikrotik router, so We had to buy `ADSL` modem(public IP `1xx.2xx.3xx.4xx`) which takes `ADSL` connection as input and provide Wifi and LAN to `mikrotik` router(has local ip `192.168.2.3`). Every thing works fine. Now I have to set up VPN server(SSTP) in `mikrotik` router to connect from home. To connect from home I need public IP, But the public IP is set for `ADSL` modem not for `mikrotik` router(where VPN server configured).

I tried port forwarding from `ADSL` modem to `mirkotik` router like, incoming traffic approch particular port(1655) forward to `192.168.2.3:443` and try connect from home labtop as (1xx.2xx.3xx.4xx:1655) this works fine but I don't like this forwarding method, Is there any other way?

**NOTE:** This setup(port forwarding) works for `windows` client not for `ubuntu` client. I can't specify gateway as `1xx.2xx.3xx.4xx:1655` in `ubuntu` network manager, I'm getting `unable to start service`.

**More Details:**
Modem: Netgear D500.
Mikrotik router: 450GL.

Answer (score 1):

The ADSL modem should have the possibility to bridge its ADSL and Ethernet interfaces, so that your Mikrotik router would get the public IP directly from your ISP.

So, change your ADSL modem from the current routed mode to bridged mode, and you should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Tero Kilkanen for reply. I have no idea how to convert ADSL modem to bridged mode. Can you give me more details about how to do or any ilnk to get more information? We are using Netgear D500 and Mikrotik router 450 GL.

Comment: With Netgear D500, the instructions for this are on page 64. You have to change `WAN Preference` from `Must use DSL WAN` to `Must use Ethernet WAN`. Then port 2 will be a bridged port.

Comment: I don't understand. If I change `WAN Preference` from `Must use DSL WAN` to `Must use Ethernet WAN` then the input to Netgear router should be `Ethernet` where as I have only `ADSL` input. How this will work.

Comment: Unfortunately that was too quick a conclusion from me, that is not the correct thing to do. And Netgear's documentation is quite confusing, all I can find about this is http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/110 , and it doesn't contain the actual instructions for bridged mode. You might need to contact Netgear on this.